# Configuration Data - JSON stored in Table versus individual fields

Tags: mysql, json, database, architecture

I have a table A that contains the definition/configuration for a form (fields, display information, etc). I perform a lookup into that table to determine what the form that is being displayed looks like. We also dynamically create tables to hold data as specified in that form or record.

When working with other developers, twice it has been suggested to store the field information in JSON format in a single field in table A instead of individual fields for configuration.

My principle concern is one of performance. We are retrieving row information from Table A or we are retrieving row information from table A and parsing it in the client.

Which is better in terms of performance? In terms of code reuse?

Comment: I should have asked an additional question: Which is better with respect to data modeling, architecture, and the ability to upgrade. We just found out the answer - having your data in JSON is great, performance is ok (negligible difference); however, unwinding where data is stored after the fact - like three months after is hard - very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, storing configuration as a serialized JSON document will give you the flexibility of changing and propagating changes easily likely with less code. Ideally, let the client do the deserialization,

Assuming documents are fairly small (<5K) processing cost is negligible, and as long as your access pattern is key/vale based the database performance should not be different from accessing any other row by  primary key. Make sure to index the key.

But more broadly I would consider the following,

- A document store for this scenario (for both the configuration and data).
- Consider separating schema definition from the user/system preferences.
- Shard data by the key (this would be a replacement for creating separate tables)

Answer (score 1):

> My principle concern is one of performance. We are retrieving row
>   information from Table A or we are retrieving row information from
>   table A and parsing it in the client.
>   Which is better in terms of performance? In terms of code reuse?

I do not see performance as a problem here.

**JSON Pros**

- Schema flexibility. If you change or add something, you need not to touch database tables
- Configuration richness. JSON is more expressive, than a database table
- Easy nested structure support

**JSON Cons**

- Inability to change only a part of JSON object. You have to deserialize it, change, serialize again and then store.
- Inability to easily change a part of many objects. Where simple `UPDATE...WHERE` can be issued for database table, you will have to read your database row by row and update each separately when using JSON.
- Weak versioning. Changing JSON schema format is not very simple and is not obvious. When you change database structure, it's always visible and straightforward process. JSON schema change is not so obvious.

If you go with JSON, I recommend to use JSON schemas to validate current versions of data. And consider making a migration regulation. If JSON schema changes, a special migration must be prepared, which will walk database and restructure all JSON data there in a single transaction.